# CodeIgniter avatars uploading

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Here's the new HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file_1" />
<input type="text" name="image_description_1" class="text-input"/>
```

Here's the new _submit function:

```
if($this->CI->input->post('file_1')){
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
$config['max_size'] = 2000;
$config['upload_path'] = realpath(APPPATH . '../assets/uploads/avatars');

$this->CI->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->CI->upload->do_upload();

$image_data = $this->CI->upload->data();

$image['description'] = $this->CI->input->post('image_description_1');
$image['user_id'] = $id;
$image['image'] = $image_data['file_name'];

$this->CI->db->insert('report_images',$image);

}
```

The description and user_id are correctly getting submitted, but the file is lost.

Should I be doing something different? Not really sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have extended the Codeigniter's upload class to fit exactly what you need. In this class i have defined two methods validate_upload and do_upload. I did not write any new code in this file instead i broke the do_upload code in two parts. validate_upload validates the upload and returns false if file is not validated and do_upload should only be used when validate_upload returns true. Here is the code.

```
Class My_Upload extends CI_Upload
{   

    public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
    }   

    public function validate_upload($field = 'userfile')
    {

        // Is $_FILES[$field] set? If not, no reason to continue.
        if ( ! isset($_FILES[$field]))
        {
            $this->set_error('upload_no_file_selected');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Is the upload path valid?
        if ( ! $this->validate_upload_path())
        {
            // errors will already be set by validate_upload_path() so just return FALSE
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Was the file able to be uploaded? If not, determine the reason why.
        if ( ! is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name']))
        {
            $error = ( ! isset($_FILES[$field]['error'])) ? 4 : $_FILES[$field]['error'];

            switch($error)
            {
                case 1: // UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
                    $this->set_error('upload_file_exceeds_limit');
                    break;
                case 2: // UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
                    $this->set_error('upload_file_exceeds_form_limit');
                    break;
                case 3: // UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL
                    $this->set_error('upload_file_partial');
                    break;
                case 4: // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
                    $this->set_error('upload_no_file_selected');
                    break;
                case 6: // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR
                    $this->set_error('upload_no_temp_directory');
                    break;
                case 7: // UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE
                    $this->set_error('upload_unable_to_write_file');
                    break;
                case 8: // UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION
                    $this->set_error('upload_stopped_by_extension');
                    break;
                default :   $this->set_error('upload_no_file_selected');
                    break;
            }

            return FALSE;
        }


        // Set the uploaded data as class variables
        $this->file_temp        =   $_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'];
        $this->file_size        =   $_FILES[$field]['size'];
        $this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]);
        $this->file_type        =   preg_replace("/^(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $this->file_type);
        $this->file_type        =   strtolower(trim(stripslashes($this->file_type), '"'));
        $this->file_name        =   $this->_prep_filename($_FILES[$field]['name']);
        $this->file_ext     =   $this->get_extension($this->file_name);
        $this->client_name  =   $this->file_name;

        // Is the file type allowed to be uploaded?
        if ( ! $this->is_allowed_filetype())
        {
            $this->set_error('upload_invalid_filetype');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // if we're overriding, let's now make sure the new name and type is allowed
        if ($this->_file_name_override != '')
        {
            $this->file_name = $this->_prep_filename($this->_file_name_override);

            // If no extension was provided in the file_name config item, use the uploaded one
            if (strpos($this->_file_name_override, '.') === FALSE)
            {
                $this->file_name .= $this->file_ext;
            }

            // An extension was provided, lets have it!
            else
            {
                $this->file_ext  = $this->get_extension($this->_file_name_override);
            }

            if ( ! $this->is_allowed_filetype(TRUE))
            {
                $this->set_error('upload_invalid_filetype');
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        // Convert the file size to kilobytes
        if ($this->file_size > 0)
        {
            $this->file_size = round($this->file_size/1024, 2);
        }

        // Is the file size within the allowed maximum?
        if ( ! $this->is_allowed_filesize())
        {
            $this->set_error('upload_invalid_filesize');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Are the image dimensions within the allowed size?
        // Note: This can fail if the server has an open_basdir restriction.
        if ( ! $this->is_allowed_dimensions())
        {
            $this->set_error('upload_invalid_dimensions');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Sanitize the file name for security
        $this->file_name = $this->clean_file_name($this->file_name);

        // Truncate the file name if it's too long
        if ($this->max_filename > 0)
        {
            $this->file_name = $this->limit_filename_length($this->file_name, $this->max_filename);
        }

        // Remove white spaces in the name
        if ($this->remove_spaces == TRUE)
        {
            $this->file_name = preg_replace("/\s+/", "_", $this->file_name);
        }

        /*
         * Validate the file name
         * This function appends an number onto the end of
         * the file if one with the same name already exists.
         * If it returns false there was a problem.
         */
        $this->orig_name = $this->file_name;

        if ($this->overwrite == FALSE)
        {
            $this->file_name = $this->set_filename($this->upload_path, $this->file_name);

            if ($this->file_name === FALSE)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        /*
         * Run the file through the XSS hacking filter
         * This helps prevent malicious code from being
         * embedded within a file.  Scripts can easily
         * be disguised as images or other file types.
         */
        if ($this->xss_clean)
        {
            if ($this->do_xss_clean() === FALSE)
            {
                $this->set_error('upload_unable_to_write_file');
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        $this->set_image_properties($this->upload_path.$this->file_name);
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function do_upload($field = 'userfile')
    {
        /*
         * Move the file to the final destination
         * To deal with different server configurations
         * we'll attempt to use copy() first.  If that fails
         * we'll use move_uploaded_file().  One of the two should
         * reliably work in most environments
         */
        if ( ! @copy($this->file_temp, $this->upload_path.$this->file_name))
        {
            if ( ! @move_uploaded_file($this->file_temp, $this->upload_path.$this->file_name))
            {
                $this->set_error('upload_destination_error');
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        /*
         * Set the finalized image dimensions
         * This sets the image width/height (assuming the
         * file was an image).  We use this information
         * in the "data" function.
         */
        return TRUE;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this form validation extension will help you to validate files before uploading, you can check their size minimum and maximum size allowed, valid file allowed type, in case of image minimum and maximum image width and height, just drop this library in you library folder and set the rule as per documentation of extension.

[MY_Form_validation](http://devbro.com/testing/ci_form_validation/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `do_upload` to a temporary directory of your choosing, or `/tmp`, do the processing you need. If it passes, create the row and store the file into your directory.

Comment: `mv` is an automic operation, `cp` is a totally different story. If you're worried about the I/O of moves, you're looking in the wrong area for optimization.

Comment: If you really want, you can access `$_FILES` directly to do any "check" operations first before you run `do_upload`