# unable to show file error message on the view page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

i am trying to show image upload error message using `flashdata` but the code which i shown  below is not  working fine. What could be the reason?

Please suggest me a solution to solve this issue.

mycontrollerPage.php

```
class Booksetups extends CI_Controller  
{
    function book($book_id = 0)
    {
       $config = array(); 
       $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/thexxr.com/Booksetups/book/pgn/';
       $config["total_rows"] = $this->Booksmodel->record_count(); 
       $config['uri_segment'] = 4; 
       $config['per_page'] = 5;  
       $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
       $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

        //------------not wroking file upload error validation------------------------------------------   
        $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/'; 
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png'; 
        $config['max_size'] = '1000'; 
        $config['max_width'] = '1920'; 
        $config['max_height'] = '1280'; 
        $config['remove_spaces'] = 'TRUE'; 
        $config['file_path'] = 'TRUE'; 
        $config['full_path']    = '/uploads/';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload("img1");
        $this->upload->do_upload("img2");
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------


       $this->pagination->initialize($config);   
       $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;   

       $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div  class="error">', '</div>')->set_rules('subject_id', 'subject_id','trim|required|min_length[1]|max_length[150]|xss_clean');
       $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div  class="error">', '</div>')->set_rules('cover_id', 'cover_id','trim|required|min_length[1]|max_length[150]|xss_clean');
       $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div  class="error">', '</div>')->set_rules('language_id', 'language_id','trim|required|min_length[1]|max_length[150]|xss_clean');
       $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div  class="error">', '</div>')->set_rules('edition_id', 'edition_id','trim|required|min_length[1]|max_length[150]|xss_clean');

        if(($this->input->post('book_id'))&& ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE))
        {  
            if( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) //trying to display error
            {
                   $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
                   $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error);
                   redirect(current_url()); 
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '1 row(s) affected.');
            $this->Booksmodel->entry_update();  
            redirect(current_url());
        }
    }
}
```

Myview.php

```
<?php echo '<fieldset><legend>'. $formtopic.'</legend>' ?>  

<?php echo validation_errors();  ?>   
<?php 
    $message = $this->session->flashdata('msg');  
    if($message)
    {
    ?>
    <div class="success" id="msgdiv"><?php echo  $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?></div> 
    <?php 
    }
?>  

<?php 
$message = $this->session->flashdata('error');  
    if($message)
    {
    ?> 
    <?php echo $error;?>   
    <!-- Here i am getting. Message like "array" why not i am getting the error message instead? --> 
<?php 
    }
?>
```

Comment: you are getting array because you are setting the flash error message as an array [$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());], try setting it to just a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will recommend using form_validation's validation_errors(). Here is how i do it.
Take a look at the library in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005081/codeigniter-validate-file-before-do-upload).
This library has two methods validate_upload (it only checks if file is valid)
and do_upload(must be used only when validate_upload returns true).

There is a file upload library available in Codeigniter [Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) is the documentation.
Copy the code of my answer and paste it in a file called MY_Upload.php and save this file in application/Code folder.
And now i define a rule like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'New Image', 'trim|callback_valid_upload');
```

When the image upload is optional you can wrap it in a condition

```
if(isset($_FILES['userfile']) AND $_FILES['userfile']['name']!= ''){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'New Image', 'trim|callback_valid_upload');   
}
```

Where userfile is file field of form.
You can see i have called a function in rule callback_valid_upload
Here is method of controller used in callback

```
public function valid_upload()
{
    $this->load->library('upload'); 

    $config['upload_path']      =   'your path here';           
    $config['allowed_types']    =   'png';
    $config['max_size']         =   2048;
    $config['max_width']        =   85;
    $config['max_height']       =   110;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->validate_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_upload', $this->upload->display_errors());
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }       
}
```

This method will check if file we are uploading is valid and will return true on success else false.
When validation is failed load form

```
View

echo validation_errors();
//blah blah
//<form action="">
//  <input type="" />
//  <input type="" />
//  <input type="" />
//</form>
```

And if you want to display the messages seperatly

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="" /> 
<?php echo form_error('userfile')?>
```

And if validation is successfull upload file now like this.

```
if($this->form_validation->run())
{
    if(isset($_FILES['userfile']) AND $_FILES['userfile']['name'] !='')
    {
        $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'); // this will upload file
        $image_data =   $this->upload->data();
        $data['image_field_name_of_table']      =   $image_data['raw_name'];
    }
    //other data in $data array here

    $id =   $this->mymodel->insert($data);
    if($id){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('notice', ' Successful');
        redirect('your url');   
    }
}else{
    //load view here
}
```

MORE EDITS :
One thing i noticed in your code is a problem

```
   $config = array(); 
   $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/thexxr.com/Booksetups/book/pgn/';
   $config["total_rows"] = $this->Booksmodel->record_count(); 
   $config['uri_segment'] = 4; 
   $config['per_page'] = 5;  
   $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
   $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload("img1");

    unset($config);

    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/'; 
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png'; 
    $config['max_size'] = '1000'; 
    $config['max_width'] = '1920'; 
    $config['max_height'] = '1280'; 
    $config['remove_spaces'] = 'TRUE'; 
    $config['file_path'] = 'TRUE'; 
    $config['full_path']    = '/uploads/';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config); //load again with new configuration
    $this->upload->do_upload("img1");
    $this->upload->do_upload("img2");
```

Comment: @Ashutosh take a look at this answer this might help

Comment: Out of all above answer. Your answer looks very nice. But it is little difficult to understand. I am a java developer & this is my first php project.

Comment: Well i did not know that. Take a look at [CodeigniterUser Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/toc.html) this will help you out.I am simplifying it then it might be helpful for you.

Comment: You have mentioned `MORE EDITS :
One thing i noticed in your code is a problem` But you didn't told me the name of the problem?

Comment: sorry see how i am using it first set config and load library then create config again and load again to upload

Comment: Sorry Once more. you have mentioned `Copy the code of my answer and paste it in a file called MY_Upload.php and save this file in application/Code folder. And now i define a rule like this` but i am litle confused because you have not said the folder name to save the file. (i.e folder name like : views,controller,model)  And also you said `Copy the code of my answer` Which answer you are saying?Because you have written your code in many places.

Comment: folder name i have mentioned application/Core in your main application folder. let suppose your application resides in www then www/myapplicaton/application/core/

Comment: i applied and a got one error : `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Upload::validate_upload() in C:\xampp\htdocs\...`  Why?

Comment: sorry then put the file in application/libraries. That's where it will work

Comment: i have one small doubt. As you said `When the image upload is optional you can wrap it in a condition` i written same as you mention above but if i reload my page i see a error like this: `A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: userfile

Filename: controllers/booksetups.php

Line Number: 87

`

Comment: OK see the edits. i have added isset to check if userfile is set

Comment: i am facing one problem with your code. Now image validation is working fine. But the uploaded image is not saving into my "uploads" folder. Why?   Before with my old code my images was saving into my `uploads` folder.

Comment: i checked my path is correct. i think in your code you have not mention `do_upload userfile` code. Which uploads images into the specified path.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23195/discussion-between-raheel-shan-and-ashutosh)

Comment: i have asked new question regarding this problem. Please help me to solve my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475500/unable-to-upload-multiple-images-to-its-upload-folder#comment20168187_14475500

Comment: the code which you provided above for `When the image upload is optional you can wrap it in a condition...` is not working. How to make a image upload uptional?

Comment: please set the condition according to your requirements so that it can work

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of my helper functions to set and show errors in CI

```
if (!function_exists('set_flash_message'))
{
    function set_flash_message($title, $message, $type='success')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->session->set_flashdata(
            'flash_message',
            array(
                'type' => $type,
                'title' => $title,
                'text' => $message));
    }
}

if (!function_exists('flash_message'))
{
    function flash_message()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $message = $CI->session->flashdata('flash_message');
        return $CI->load->view('desktop/flash_message', $message, TRUE);
    }
}
```

You can set message from controller :

```
set_flash_message('Error', 'Something went wrong', 'error');
```

and show error from view

```
<?php echo flash_message(); ?>
```

Comment: the top code which you have provided(`if (!function_exists('set_flash_message'))
{...`)where should i write? In model or controller or ..?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that.
Functions that You want to use anywhere in your application (just like base_url() and site_url()), should be placed in custom helper files.
So, in application/helpers dir, make file called custom_helper.php
and put my functions there.
Then, in your controller just put 
$this->load->helper('custom');
and you can use these functions everywhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I have said in my comment;

> you are getting array because you are setting the flash error message
>   as an array [`$error = array('error' =>
>   $this->upload->display_errors());`], try setting it to just a string

If you look at the function in the source code, it either takes a hash array OR a string.
If an array is passed then it will set the flashdata with the key as the flash message type, message with the value; ignoring the second parameter.
If you pass two arguments as strings it will set the flashdata key with the first string.

So either do;

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'something went wrong');
```

Or

```
$this->session->set_flashdata(array('error', 'something went wrong'));
```

Code from the source:

```
function set_flashdata($newdata = array(), $newval = '')
    {
        if (is_string($newdata))
        {
            $newdata = array($newdata => $newval);
        }

        if (count($newdata) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($newdata as $key => $val)
            {
                $flashdata_key = $this->flashdata_key.':new:'.$key;
                $this->set_userdata($flashdata_key, $val);
            }
        }
    }
```