# unable to upload multiple images to its upload folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

from my below code i am trying to upload 4 images, but  i am only  able to upload  last image to my `upload` folder.

My image validation and all the other task is working fine. But  only i  have problem with the multiple images to upload into its distinction folder.

Please check my below code and help to solve my problem.

MyController.php

```
class Booksetups extends CI_Controller  {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('Booksmodel');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

    public function valid_upload()
    {
        $this->load->library('upload');

        $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
        $config['max_size']         =   2048;
        $config['max_width']        =   385;
        $config['max_height']       =   410;

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->validate_upload('img1')  || !$this->upload->validate_upload('img2')  || !$this->upload->validate_upload('img3')  || !$this->upload->validate_upload('img4') ) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_upload', $this->upload->display_errors());
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }


    function book($book_id = 0)
    {
        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/Booksetups/book/pgn/';
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->Booksmodel->record_count();
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $config['per_page'] = 17;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';


        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;


        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div  class="error">', '</div>')->set_rules('book_title', '"Title"','trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[150]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div  class="error">', '</div>')->set_rules('edition_id', '"Edition Name"','trim|min_length[1]|max_length[150]|xss_clean');



        //---------------------validating images---------------------------

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('img1', 'Image 1', 'trim|xss_clean|callback_valid_upload');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('img2', 'Image 2', 'trim|xss_clean|callback_valid_upload');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('img3', 'Image 3', 'trim|xss_clean|callback_valid_upload');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('img4', 'Image 4', 'trim|xss_clean|callback_valid_upload');



        //-----------Here i am uploading my images into my specified folder-------------------------------
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
            $this->upload->do_upload('img1');
            $this->upload->do_upload('img2');
            $this->upload->do_upload('img3');
            $this->upload->do_upload('img4');
            $this->Booksmodel->entry_insert();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '1 row(s) inserted.');
            redirect(current_url());
        }
        ................
        ................
```

My_Upload.php

```
Class My_Upload extends CI_Upload
{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function validate_upload($field = 'img1')
    {

        // Is $_FILES[$field] set? If not, no reason to continue.
        if (! isset($_FILES[$field])) {
            $this->set_error('upload_no_file_selected');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Is the upload path valid?
        if (! $this->validate_upload_path()) {
            // errors will already be set by validate_upload_path() so just return FALSE
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Was the file able to be uploaded? If not, determine the reason why.
        if (! is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'])) {
            $error = ( ! isset($_FILES[$field]['error'])) ? 4 : $_FILES[$field]['error'];

            switch ($error) {
            case 1:
                // UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
                $this->set_error('upload_file_exceeds_limit');
                break;
            case 2:
                // UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
                $this->set_error('upload_file_exceeds_form_limit');
                break;
            case 3:
                // UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL
                $this->set_error('upload_file_partial');
                break;
            case 4:
                // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
                $this->set_error('upload_no_file_selected');
                break;
            case 6:
                // UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR
                $this->set_error('upload_no_temp_directory');
                break;
            case 7:
                // UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE
                $this->set_error('upload_unable_to_write_file');
                break;
            case 8:
                // UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION
                $this->set_error('upload_stopped_by_extension');
                break;
                default :   $this->set_error('upload_no_file_selected');
                break;
            }

            return FALSE;
        }


        // Set the uploaded data as class variables
        $this->file_temp        =   $_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'];
        $this->file_size        =   $_FILES[$field]['size'];
        $this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]);
        $this->file_type        =   preg_replace("/^(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $this->file_type);
        $this->file_type        =   strtolower(trim(stripslashes($this->file_type), '"'));
        $this->file_name        =   $this->_prep_filename($_FILES[$field]['name']);
        $this->file_ext     =   $this->get_extension($this->file_name);
        $this->client_name  =   $this->file_name;

        // Is the file type allowed to be uploaded?
        if (! $this->is_allowed_filetype()) {
            $this->set_error('upload_invalid_filetype');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // if we're overriding, let's now make sure the new name and type is allowed
        if ($this->_file_name_override != '') {
            $this->file_name = $this->_prep_filename($this->_file_name_override);

            // If no extension was provided in the file_name config item, use the uploaded one
            if (strpos($this->_file_name_override, '.') === FALSE) {
                $this->file_name .= $this->file_ext;
            }

            // An extension was provided, lets have it!
            else
            {
                $this->file_ext  = $this->get_extension($this->_file_name_override);
            }

            if (! $this->is_allowed_filetype(TRUE)) {
                $this->set_error('upload_invalid_filetype');
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        // Convert the file size to kilobytes
        if ($this->file_size > 0) {
            $this->file_size = round($this->file_size/1024, 2);
        }

        // Is the file size within the allowed maximum?
        if (! $this->is_allowed_filesize()) {
            $this->set_error('upload_invalid_filesize');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Are the image dimensions within the allowed size?
        // Note: This can fail if the server has an open_basdir restriction.
        if (! $this->is_allowed_dimensions()) {
            $this->set_error('upload_invalid_dimensions');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Sanitize the file name for security
        $this->file_name = $this->clean_file_name($this->file_name);

        // Truncate the file name if it's too long
        if ($this->max_filename > 0) {
            $this->file_name = $this->limit_filename_length($this->file_name, $this->max_filename);
        }

        // Remove white spaces in the name
        if ($this->remove_spaces == TRUE) {
            $this->file_name = preg_replace("/\s+/", "_", $this->file_name);
        }

        /*
* Validate the file name
* This function appends an number onto the end of
* the file if one with the same name already exists.
* If it returns false there was a problem.
*/
        $this->orig_name = $this->file_name;

        if ($this->overwrite == FALSE) {
            $this->file_name = $this->set_filename($this->upload_path, $this->file_name);

            if ($this->file_name === FALSE) {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        /*
* Run the file through the XSS hacking filter
* This helps prevent malicious code from being
* embedded within a file.  Scripts can easily
* be disguised as images or other file types.
*/
        if ($this->xss_clean) {
            if ($this->do_xss_clean() === FALSE) {
                $this->set_error('upload_unable_to_write_file');
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        $this->set_image_properties($this->upload_path.$this->file_name);
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function do_upload($field = 'img1')
    {
        /*
* Move the file to the final destination
* To deal with different server configurations
* we'll attempt to use copy() first.  If that fails
* we'll use move_uploaded_file().  One of the two should
* reliably work in most environments
*/
        if (! @copy($this->file_temp, $this->upload_path.$this->file_name)) {
            if (! @move_uploaded_file($this->file_temp, $this->upload_path.$this->file_name)) {
                $this->set_error('upload_destination_error');
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        /*
* Set the finalized image dimensions
* This sets the image width/height (assuming the
* file was an image).  We use this information
* in the "data" function.
*/
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

MyViewForm.php

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Booksetups/book');?>

<?php echo form_hidden('book_id',$fbook_id['value']);?>

<input type="file" name="img1" />
<input type="file" name="img2" />
<input type="file" name="img3" />
<input type="file" name="img4" />
<?php 
    echo  form_submit($submitbtn);
    echo form_reset($resetbtn);
?>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm an old fa*t, but I just love the times when uploading an image costed only about 2 minutes of programming and max 20 lines of code.

Comment: @MihaiIorga what do you mean?

Comment: :) I was just commenting about hating "new generation" uploading scripts. :)

Comment: i think you have same field name for all inputs of file therefore its taking the last one.

Comment: can you display your view form?

Comment: @MihaiIorga Please help me to solve this problem. I am struggling since 2 days for this

Comment: @raheelshan i uploaded my viewform page. Please check it above

Comment: What is the filename of the only uploaded image? Is it like image1.jpg image2.jpg.jpg image3.jpg.jpg.jpg ?

Comment: @edwardmp its same like the name of image which i chosen to upload.

Comment: Try this: Amend the Upload.php files located in the library folder.
Comment out line 935:

`$filename = $this->file_name;`

Comment: @edwardmp sorry. What do you mean by `Try this: Amend the Upload.php files located in the library folder. Comment out line 935: $filename = $this->file_name`

Comment: Change it. Delete or comment out that line.

Comment: @edwardmp there is no any line like `$filename = $this->file_name` in my Upload.php page

Comment: `$config['upload_path'] = '/uploads/';`

Comment: @Boulevard as you said i made changes but getting error while uploading  a  images `The upload path does not appear to be valid.`

Comment: where are you working local or Server?

Comment: on localhost . My url is showing like this `http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/Booksetups/book`

Comment: try setting this upload path <?php echo base_url() . 'uploads/'?> and see if it works

Comment: i tried keeping like this `$config['upload_path'] =base_url().'uploads/' ;` And also with this `$config['upload_path'] = 'http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/uploads/';`     But both is showing error like `The upload path does not appear to be valid.`

Answer (score 1):

Use uploadify jquery plugin.Its easy to use and fully customized with real time progress bar and many more features.

[Uploadify demo](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/)

Answer (score 0):

Debug your do_upload function,  you are not using local variable $ field anywhere